# Itertools takes very long time to run

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-itertools

I am using itertools in python2.7. I want to find all combinations (without repeatation). I have list of length 30 as iterable. While I save iterable object as list, it hangs or takes very long time. Can someone please help me with this..

```
#!usr/bin/python
import itertools
a = range(30)
list1 = []
for i in range(30):
    list1 = list(itertools.combinations(a,i))
```

Comment: You gotta get 2**30 combinations, that won't be fast.

Comment: yeah alko so is there any alternative?

Comment: What are you using that list for?

Comment: You should specify what do you wanna do with those

Comment: I give example with 4 digits. What I want is if I have a = [1,2,3,4] then I need all possible combinations, meaning 1,2,3,4,12,13,14,23,24,34,123,234,124,134,1234

Comment: @user2566909 I meant, what will you be using them for? Looping through them? Random lookups? Just checking the length...?

Comment: No this is just part of a long code, which has to find all possible combinations between any two digits. I feel the other code is irrelevant to put here. It works fine with smaller length of list but not with larger. And yes I will be looping through the list I have got from itertools.

Comment: I have 30 nodes in list. [nod0, nod1,...,nod29]. I want to find all possible combinations, from node 0 to node 29, which will skip any 0,1,2,...,28 nodes.
Like skipping 1 nod may skip nod1 or nod2 or nod3 and so on, skipping two may skip nod1 and nod2, or nod2 and nod7 such any combinations upto skipping all intermediate 28 nodes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you're trying to do here is create a series of lists of tuples that total an extremely large number of elements - more specifically, 2**30 = 1,073,741,824 tuples, each of which will contain, on average, 15 integers. That's 16,106,127,360 (sixteen billion) integers. Even if you had enough memory to store them all, it's obviously going to take a very long time.

The chances are that you're coming at your problem from the wrong direction (see [the XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/201929)). If you post a new question that explains the problem you're actually trying to solve, there's a chance someone may be able to help, but as it stands, your question boils down to "why does trying to do an unreasonably large amount of work take an unreasonably large amount of time?", which no-one's going to be able to help you with.